# Metro Style Datatable Styling jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

Is there any Metro Style CSS styling plugin for the JQuery Datatables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs)

Or you could create one yourself. The Metro style is very easy to replicate with the Segoe font

Comment: I was wanting something like "datatable theme" which once you put in the datatable initialization it would take care of the looks ? am already using the metro JS for animating the grids